# Filter array of objects with multiple criteria and types in Swift

Tags: swift, filter

I am trying to do some complex filtering in my app and I am to a point where I don't know what to do next. My data consistes of an array of dictionaries where the values in each of the dictionaries can be `String`, `Int` or `[String]`.

```
let person1: [String : Any] = ["first_name" : "John",
                               "last_name" : "Smith",
                               "age" : 21,
                               "skills" : ["C#", "Java", "Swift"]]
let person2: [String : Any] = ["first_name" : "Kim",
                               "last_name" : "Smith",
                               "age" : 28,
                               "skills" : ["Java", "Swift"]]
let person3: [String : Any] = ["first_name" : "Kate",
                               "last_name" : "Bell",
                               "age" : 24,
                               "skills" : ["C#"]]


var people = [person1, person2, person3]
```

I let the user choose how to filter this data and create a dictionary of filter criteria. This dictionary can have any number of keys and values.

```
let filters: [String : [Any]] = ["age" : [28, 24],
                                 "skills" : ["Java", "Swift"]]
```

In this example I want to show persons who are `age` 28 or 24 and have a `skills` of Java or Swift, which would be `person2`

Here is what I have so far but it only works with `Int` values:

```
for (key, values) in filters {
    var filteredItems = people.filter {
        var match = false
        for filterValue in values {
            if $0[key] as! Int == filterValue as! Int {
                match = true
                break
            }
            else {
                match = false
            }
        }
        return match
    }
    people = filteredItems
}
```

Comment: You would have a significantly easier time if you weren't using dictionaries to do the jobs of objects/structs

Comment: @Alexander I understand but in my apps case the data is not always the same and I don't always know what keys are in the people objects.

Comment: That's still easily modelled by objects/structs with optional properties. Fundamentally the issue you're running into is that of the type erasure of heterogeneous dictionaries. To resolve this, it's easiest to just use a data structure with strong typing ... objects/structs.

Comment: @Alexander Can you give me an example of how you would do this with objects/structs using my sample data?

Comment: Yes, I'll be free in a bit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how I would do this:

```
struct Person {
    let firstName: String
    let lastName: String
    let age: Int
    let skills: [String]
    
    enum Filter {
        enum FilterType<T: Hashable> {
            case one(of: [T])
            case all(of: [T])
            
            // Match against a property that's a single value
            func matches(_ value: T) -> Bool {
                switch self {
                    case .one(let filterValues): return filterValues.contains(value)
                    case .all(let filterValues): return filterValues.count == 1 && filterValues[0] == value
                }
            }
            
            // Match against a property that's a list of values
            func matches(_ values: [T]) -> Bool {
                switch self {
                    case .one(let filterValues): return !Set(filterValues).intersection(values).isEmpty
                    case .all(let filterValues): return Set(filterValues).isSuperset(of: values)
                }
            }
        }
        
        case age(is: FilterType<Int>)
        case skills(is: FilterType<String>)
        
        func matches(_ p: Person) -> Bool {
            switch self {
                case .age(let filterValues): return filterValues.matches(p.age)
                case .skills(let filterValues): return filterValues.matches(p.skills)
            }
        }
    }
}

extension Array where Element == Person.Filter {
    func atLeastOneMatch(_ p: Person) -> Bool {
        self.contains(where: { $0.matches(p) })
    }
    
    func matchesAll(_ p: Person) -> Bool {
        self.allSatisfy { $0.matches(p) }
    }
}

let people = [
    Person(
        firstName: "John",
        lastName : "Smith",
        age: 21,
        skills: ["C#", "Java", "Swift"]
    ),
    Person(
        firstName: "Kim",
        lastName : "Smith",
        age: 28,
        skills: ["Java", "Swift"]
    ),
    Person(
        firstName: "Kate",
        lastName: "Bell",
        age: 24,
        skills: ["C#"]
    ),
]


let filters: [Person.Filter] = [
    .age(is: .one(of: [28, 24])),
    .skills(is: .one(of: ["Java", "Swift"])),
]

let peopleWhoMatchAllFilters = people.filter(filters.matchesAll)
print(peopleWhoMatchAllFilters)

let peopleWhoMatchAtLeastOneFilter = people.filter(filters.atLeastOneMatch)
print(peopleWhoMatchAtLeastOneFilter)
```

I've extended the filtering capability to be able to specify wether all values of a filter should be matched (e.g. a person must know Java AND Swift AND C#) or at least one (e.g. a person must know AT LEAST Java OR Swift OR C#)

Comment: Thanks for this example, it works great. The thing with my situation (which I didn't fully explain in my original question) is that that `person` data is JSON pulled from a server. That data can change at any time server side, for example, what if `"favorite_color" : "Blue"` was added? Can that be handled without adding a `favoriteColor` value to the `Person` object?

Comment: @Chris That's an interesting problem. I think you'll need to fully commit to everything being dynamic (a `[String: Any]` shitshow) or fully static (a maintenance pain). You're in this middle ground that'll make pretty much anything difficult.

Comment: @Chris How often do you envision such changes to the data model? That is, how much of a burden would it be to update your Swift models to keep in sync with the service data model?

Comment: The server side data actually wouldn't change that often and I could definitely do an update to the app data model when needed. There is, however, another component to my app where the user can completely change the type of data being filtered, for example, they can switch from working with People objects to Car objects.

Comment: @Chris That's find, all you would need to do is define a new `enum` like the `Person.Filter` that I made. You could even extract the `matches` function into a protocol, to which all filters conform. Also, you can extract and reuse `FilterType<T: Hashable>` amount all Filter types

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Chris No problem. Let me know if you have any more questions