# Filter An Array Of Arrays By A Value In Firestore Swift

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I'm looking to filter an array of arrays by specific value of one of the keys located within each array. Each nested array is read in from Firestore.

As an object, each nested array would look like this:

```
struct Video { 
var url: String
var submissionDate: Timestamp
var submittingUser: String  
}
```

I'm reading it in like this:

```
videos = document.get("videos") as? [[String : Any]] ?? nil
```

So far so good, but when I filter it like this:

```
filteredVideos = videos.filter { $0[2].contains(self.userIdentification) }
```

I can't do it without getting the error "Reference to member 'contains' cannot be resolved without a contextual type," an error which I was unable to find any relevant information on SO about.

I have read that some people say "Don't use arrays in Firestore!" but this is a build requirement.

Anyone have any ideas? Basically just need all arrays within the array where userId == submittingUser.

Reference Article:

I tried the answer from here: [How to filter out a Array of Array's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47026624/how-to-filter-out-a-array-of-arrays) but no luck for this situation.

Comment: What does your array structure look like? Have you tried anything like `videos.filter { $0[2].submittingUser == userId }` This should filter the arrays by its 3rd element where `submittingUser` equals `userId`.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually an array of dictionaries, not an array of arrays. All you need to do is construct the right predicate for the filter.

This is basically what your Firestore data looks like:

```
let videos: [[String: Any]] = [
    ["url": "http://www...", "submittingUser": "user1"],
    ["url": "http://www...", "submittingUser": "user2"]
]
```

This is the user you're looking for:

```
let userIdentification = "user2"
```

This is the predicate for the filer:

```
let filteredVideos = videos.filter { (video) -> Bool in
    if let submittingUser = video["submittingUser"] as? String,
       submittingUser == userIdentification {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

You can shorthand this down to a single line if you're okay with force-unwrapping the dictionary (if you're 100% certain every video will have a valid `submittingUser` value):

```
let filteredVideos = videos.filter({ $0["submittingUser"] as! String == userIdentification })
```